# The determinant is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove that the determinant is the only function that has the properties of the determinant (multilinearity, being alternating, $\det(I)=1$).

In my notes we started to prove it like: suppose there is another such function (say $g$)...
But from then on I can't make sense of it.